# MVC5 POST form retrieves data from previous index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I populated my View with a model passed in from the Controller. Each loop will also generate a hyperlink button which **should** pass in the guid. However, when I clicked on the button and initiated the ***POST*** request, the guid belongs to the button of a previous index.

However, after checking the element using Chrome's inspection tool, the button has the correct guid attached to it. Just that when the button is clicked (POSTing), the guid that is passed as a parameter belongs to the previous index's.

For example:

Button A (GUID 1000)

Button B (GUID 2000)

Button C (GUID 3000)

When I click on Button B, the guid that is passed for POSTing is 1000, which belongs to Button A.

***Index.cshtml***

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
           <tr>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PatientName)
              </td>
              <td>
                 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NRIC)
              </td>
              <td>
              @using (Html.BeginForm("Patient", "MainController", new { guid = item.PatientId }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitRequest" })) {
               @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <a href="javascript:document.getElementById('submitRequest').submit()" onclick="return confirm('A pop up message.');" class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus" title="Request"></a>
                    }
               </td>
             </tr>
          }
```

**MainController.cs**

```
// POST: Doctor/Patient
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Patient(string guid) {
            try {
                if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                    var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                    db.Appeal.Add(new Appeal {
                        DoctorId = User.Identity.GetUserId(),
                        PatientId = guid, // issue is here.
                        Time = currentTime, 
                        IsApprove = false
                    });
                    TempData["Message"] = "Appeal is being processed. Check the Request page for outcome.";
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Patient");
                }
            } catch (DataException dex) {
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Patient");
        }
```

May I know where did I go wrong? Have been trying to fix this for past 1 hours, just can't seem to figure out what's causing it.

Comment: You creating invalid html because of duplicate `id` attributes - `new { id = "submitRequest" }` in the form. Remove the `id` attribute, replace the `<a>` with a submit button and handle its `.click()` event to display the confirm (and cancel the submit if necessary)

Comment: And `if (ModelState.IsValid)` is pointless - its always `true` because you don't bind to a model

Comment: Thank you for your assistance! I'll make the necessary admendments and update again in awhile. Regarding the ModelState, I will be binding it to a model in awhile. Thanks for spotting that too!

Comment: I have updated my post with the solution.

Comment: Answers don't belong in questions :)  Add you own answer and roll back the edit to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

Updated ***Index.cshtml*** as follow.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Patient", "Doctor", new { guid = item.PatientId }, FormMethod.Post)) {
                                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                            <button class="btn btn-success glyphicon glyphicon-plus" type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')"></button>
                                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Patient", "Doctor", new { guid = item.PatientId }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "submitRequest" }))
```

The `id` is same for all form elements and you are submitting those forms through javascript using the same `id` element. So when you call

```
document.getElementById('submitRequest`)
```

It will always return the first form element with the given `id`. You need to have different `id` attribute attached to each form element.

Comment: is `document.getElementById('submitRequest`)` and `document.getElementById('submitRequest')[0]` is same ?

Comment: According to HTML specifications, id attributes should be unique if they are not, the HTML is malformed.  And in case of unique id, `document.getElementById` will return one element rather than an array of elements.